# php script duplicate image into the database

Tags: php

i have php script it keep downloading feeds from the internet.
but unfortunately it keep duplicate the image feed into the database.
part from the image, the script working fine on other feed like `description`,`link`, `title`.

**php script**

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

$url = "http://www.albaldnews.com/rss.php?cat=24";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

if($rss)
{
    echo '<h1>'.$rss->channel->title.'</h1>';
    echo '<li>'.$rss->channel->pubDate.'</li>';
    $items = $rss->channel->item;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $enclosure = $item->enclosure[0]['url'];

        $ch = curl_init ("$enclosure");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch,        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1); 
        $rawdata=curl_exec ($ch); 
        curl_close ($ch);

        $img=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$rawdata);

        $query = "SELECT image from feedtable where link = '$img'"; 
        $result=    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows == 0)
        {
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO feedtable (image)VALUES ('$img')"; 
            $result1=    mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

            echo "image added\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "duplicate entry\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: So, I've read your code 3 times, and finally my question is: why do you `INSERT  ... (image)` but when `SELECT ... WHERE link=` is it what you want?

Comment: While inserting you only enter the value for `image` column, but in your select you check if that value exists in `link` column. Are image and link different?

Comment: @ Kim Alexande thank you, i didnt see it i replay it with image.

Comment: @ Ananth my problem solved it was syntax mistake.